# TypeError: req.isAuthenticated is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, mern

I want to add a function called **isAuth** and when i refresh home page it throws err TypeError: req.isAuthenticated is not a function

> if(! req.isAuthenticated()){
>              ^
>
> TypeError: req.isAuthenticated is not a function
>
> at isAuth (E:\My Drive\src code\node.js\Revision\regSys\routes\index.js:117:12)
>
> at E:\My Drive\src code\node.js\Revision\regSys\node_modules\hbs\lib\hbs.js:94:16
>
> at E:\My Drive\src code\node.js\Revision\regSys\node_modules\hbs\lib\hbs.js:85:9
>
> at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)

**index.js**

```
//isAuthenticated
function isAuth(req, res, next){
  if(! req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.redirect('login')
    return;
  }
  next();
}
```

**node V: 10.16.1**

---

Comment: It means that your `req` object does not have a function property called `isAuthenticated` and when invoking that function it is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it!
The problem was i called `isAuth()` function wrongly
it was

```
//wrong 
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', isAuth, { title: 'Home'});
});

//isAuthenticated
function isAuth(req , res , next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      res.redirect("/");
      next();
  } else{
      res.redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

and that is wrong, **so it have to be**

```
//correcting
router.get('/', isAuth,function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Home'});
});
// .........
```